# Selector tag in xml file has some problems with SVGs

Tags: android, xml, svg

I'm trying to achieve that whenever the users touches the icon it changes color to a darker one, I have done it perfectly using PNGs but for some reason it's not working anymore since I used SVGs files:

filter_icon.xml:

```
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/filter_icon_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/filter_icon_pressed" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/filter_icon_static" />
</selector>
```

filter_icon_static.xml:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="130dp"
    android:height="130dp"
    android:viewportWidth="130"
    android:viewportHeight="130">
  <path
      android:pathData="M125,9L5,9a5,5 0,0 0,0 10L125,19a5,5 0,0 0,0 -10Z"
      android:fillColor="#13293d"/>
  <path
      android:pathData="M125,42.84L5,42.84a5,5 0,0 0,0 10L125,52.84a5,5 0,0 0,0 -10Z"
      android:fillColor="#13293d"/>
  <path
      android:pathData="M125,76.9L5,76.9a5,5 0,0 0,0 10L125,86.9a5,5 0,0 0,0 -10Z"
      android:fillColor="#13293d"/>
  <path
      android:pathData="M125,111L5,111a5,5 0,0 0,0 10L125,121a5,5 0,0 0,0 -10Z"
      android:fillColor="#13293d"/>
  <path
      android:pathData="M5,14.03a14,14.03 0,1 0,28 0a14,14.03 0,1 0,-28 0z"
      android:fillColor="#13293d"/>
  <path
      android:pathData="M102,47.85a14,14.03 0,1 0,28 0a14,14.03 0,1 0,-28 0z"
      android:fillColor="#13293d"/>
  <path
      android:pathData="M51,81.91a14,14.03 0,1 0,28 0a14,14.03 0,1 0,-28 0z"
      android:fillColor="#13293d"/>
  <path
      android:pathData="M85,115.97a14,14.03 0,1 0,28 0a14,14.03 0,1 0,-28 0z"
      android:fillColor="#13293d"/>
</vector>
```

What should I make to let the color of the filter icon change once the user touches it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ref : http://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html,

http://wiki.workassis.com/category/android/android-xml/

```
<ImageView
.
.
.
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
android:clickable="true"
```